# Balance returning zero after sending KETH to it

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, kovan

I have sent the following transactions to the account [0x2D76d8729F9Cfa5bC3CEba8a504400FE30bb53D2](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x2D76d8729F9Cfa5bC3CEba8a504400FE30bb53D2):

- [0x8667bd1859a5ccc99bcc77b38c5453195bf32b308b4038ae409b47b002546344](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x8667bd1859a5ccc99bcc77b38c5453195bf32b308b4038ae409b47b002546344)
- [0x048be71bb286c0cd4546f882874e8c7d52a46ad6bb23132a2753807b67d7680b](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x048be71bb286c0cd4546f882874e8c7d52a46ad6bb23132a2753807b67d7680b)

However, when I try to query the balance using the code below, I get a balance of 0

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

var myenv map[string]string

const envLoc = ".env"

func loadEnv() {
    var err error
    if myenv, err = godotenv.Read(envLoc); err != nil {
        log.Printf("could not load env from %s: %v", envLoc, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    loadEnv()

    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := ethclient.Dial("http://kovan.infura.io/v3/<!REDACTED>)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not connect to Ethereum gateway: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    accountAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x2D76d8729F9Cfa5bC3CEba8a504400FE30bb53D2")
    balance, _ := client.BalanceAt(ctx, accountAddress, nil)
    fmt.Printf("Balance: %d\n", balance)
}
```

I would appreciate pointers as to what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infura doues not allow unencrypted HTTP requests.  Should be `https://kovan.infura.io/v3/...`.